Select all small faces in solid mode from distance?
Is there any way to select all faces from a distance in solid view (not wire or x-ray)? When I select many small faces from a distance it skips a lot of them, see images below.
Edit: I only want to select the visual faces from a specific view.
Edit2: In the example I only have 1 sphere, in reality it's over 300 and can not zoom in to every geometry.
Example: many faces are not selected.


I have tried to set the clipping narrow to the object without success. Any tips?

Have you tried hitting the 'A' key to select All?

It's because the distance between your vertices at that distance is smaller than a single pixel on-screen. The selection is based on what is visible on screen. If 50% of your vertices have been culled because they aren't even visible then how can you select them.

If your aim is to select all vertices included in the selection box, press Ctrl L after selection (Select all linked geometry).

Thanks, that right. But if I only want to select all the visual faces from a specific view.

As @Jakemoyo says you'd have to scroll in before you can select them.
